# Issue with first Ruby On Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, command-line

I'm trying to launch my first rails application but it's not working.

I installed yarn and checked that it had been installed.

I then typed `rails webpacker:install`. Node didn't install for some reason, I typed post install for node and it still didn't work.

For some background, I have a mid 2012 Mac with OS Mojave 10.14.6
,Ruby version 2.6.3
,Ruby on rails version 6.0.0
and Yarn version 1.19.1

My code:

```
(base) Apples-MBP:~ apple$ cd desktop
(base) Apples-MBP:desktop apple$ cd portfolio
(base) Apples-MBP:portfolio apple$ rails s
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.0.0 application starting in development 
=> Run `rails server --help` for more startup options
RAILS_ENV=development environment is not defined in config/webpacker.yml, falling back to production environment
Exiting
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

After this, I got a list of files and gems that are probably too lengthy to post here.

I expected Rails to confirm it was running so I could see my work on localhost:3000 but this was the end result

```
/Users/apple/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.6.3/gems/webpacker-4.0.7/lib/webpacker/configuration.rb:91:in `rescue in load': Webpacker configuration file not found /Users/apple/Desktop/portfolio/config/webpacker.yml. Please run rails webpacker:install Error: No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /Users/apple/Desktop/portfolio/config/webpacker.yml (RuntimeError)
(base) Apples-MBP:portfolio apple$
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You should create a "development" section in your config/webpacker.yml

Comment: The `rails s` error indicates `Please run rails webpacker:install` - you'll need to get that to run successfully before the server will boot up. What version of node are you using, and how is it installed?

Comment: Node didn't install successfully, even after I tried with the post-install command. I'll try and install node separately and then run rails webpacker install again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First & foremost install brew type the following in the terminal

`/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`

Then install Yarn :

```
brew install yarn
```

Or to do this manually :

```
curl -o- -L https://yarnpkg.com/install.sh | bash
```

Now run the command :

```
yarn install
rails webpacker:install
```

Comment: I had already installed Homebrew, Rails works now, all I needed to do was reinstall it and install Yarn separately! Thanks for all the answers.